# When I want to change the color of an object, some other objects change too

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a window tool for a project I am working on. When you select some objects in the scene and picked a color and hit Apply, it should change the color of the objects you have selected. Which it does. But it changes some other objects as well, even though they weren't selected.

I think that has to do with that I am setting the color of the SharedMaterial on the renderer, but if I were to use the normal Material.Color, it gives me an error that it is leaking materials into the scene and that I might use SharedMaterial instead.

Now my question is: How do I fix this problem without having to create a new material every time I need a new color. Because that is why I made the tool (change the color of an object without having to create a new material for it).

```
private void OnGUI()
{
    newColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Color", newColor);
    EditorGUILayout.Space();

    if (GUILayout.Button("Apply color"))
    {
        foreach (GameObject element in Selection.gameObjects)
        {
            Renderer renderer = element.GetComponent<Renderer>();

            if (renderer != null)
            {
                renderer.sharedMaterial.color = newColor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is much more useful if you post the code here, rather than a screenshot.  Have you run this through the debugger, and seen whether the objects in the `Selection.gameObjects` collection is what you expect it to be?

Comment: What framework is that? This is not standard C#, is it Unity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of using renderer.sharedMaterial you should use renderer.material.

renderer.sharedMaterial will make the change for all objects that use that material. If you change just renderer.material, Unity will create an instance (internal runtime copy) of that material and just use that.

Note: this will break any material batching this modified object is part of since internally it's a different material.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in Unity.
You have to change the color of the material. If that material is applied to other objects, then those will also be changed. So, you'll need to create multiple materials for different colored objects.

Comment: So you can't edit the RGB of the material the object has?

Comment: You can change the RGB of the material, which is independent of object. So, if multiple objects have the same material, changing the material color will affect all the objects.

Comment: Are you saying materials aren't copied for each object/component they're attached to? ...

Comment: Exactly. For test purpose, just take 2 3D objects in Unity. Create a new material. Assign that material to both the objects. Now, edit the material and both objects will be changed. It is the same, if you change it for one object only, as they refer to the same material.

Comment: you can do what the other answer says (the one from GameDevBryant)

Comment: Whoa, didn't know that one.